# Delay of SystemSound after UIRefreshControl ends refreshing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile

so I have this problem where I would like to have a a sound play everytime the UIRefreshControl endsRefreshing. I tried AVAudioPlayer but found the latency to be too great. Furthermore, I tried using the AudioToolbox class in order to use SystemSounds. I am not using a system sound, but rather my own .wav file.

There was a slight increase in the amount of speed it took for the sound to play after the UIRefreshControl endsRefreshing.

```
- (void) playRefreshSound {
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"perc1" ofType:@"wav"];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Here is the function that I am using to play the sound which I then call in a different view controller.

```
Audio *audio = [[Audio alloc] init];
[audio playRefreshSound];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Bes